# brain teaser - coin game

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this brain teaser, and have some problems in solving it:

> > > There are $N$ coins disposed over a circle, and all of them are face up. $N$ turns are played as follows: at each $m$-th turn, one every $m$ coins is flipped, starting from the $m$-th coin, and going on around the circle of coins till one already flipped is met. After $N$ turns, which ones will be face down?

I figured out that when $m$ and $N$ do not share any divisor, each coin will be flipped, otherwise all coins with location $i$ sharing a divisor with $m$ will be fipped. I supposed that then the number $M$ of locations sharing a divisor with $N$ should be even, but I am not sure of this. So depending on wheter $N$ is even or odd, given that $M$ should be even (?), I flip the coins an even or an odd number of times. Am I on the right track? How would you solve it?

EDIT: nice variant, I do not stop flipping when I meet a coin I already flipped, but when I flipped N coins.. this variant I just chose not to approach it.

Comment: Form a table.  For each $N=1$ to $10$, find which coins end up face down.  That might give you ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for every integer $m$, all coins that are a multiple of $\gcd (N,m)$ get flipped. Now since $\gcd(N, m) = \gcd(N, N-m)$, we can split the integers $1$ to $N$ into pairs which cancel out, (e.g. $(1,N-1), (2,N-2), \ldots$) leaving only $m = N$, and possibly $m=\frac{N}{2}$ if $N$ is even. Therefore the face up coins are $N$ if $N$ is odd, and $\frac{N}{2}$ if $N$ is even.

Comment: That does not work here; suppose you have $3$ coins. In the first turn, you flip all of them. In the second turn, you start by flipping coin 2, then you flip coin $2+2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, then you flip coin 3, then you stop (because the second coin has already been flipped). So you flipped every coin in round 3. In round 3, you flip coin 3 only. So at the end you flip coins 1 and 2 twice, and coin 3 three times.

Comment: (You are solving the “corridor with lightbulbs” puzzle, but here you are going around the circle, rather than running out the end, so the argument about factors doesn’t work)

Comment: Yes exactly, I was able to solve the corridor with lightbulbs puzzle, but adding the circle thing is killing me ..

Comment: Maybe think of modular arithmetic. If x $\equiv$ 1 mod m, then every coin will get flipped. So it's a matter of finding gcd of (N,m) for all m.

Comment: @marco Ah, sorry about that, I misread the question. I’ve fixed my answer now.

Comment: @auscrypt to be honest it does not seem to me to be the true answer. I mean, I decided to make everything more complex, so I wrote a python code that computes this task, and discovered that the only coin who is face down is going to be either the half of $N$ (if $N$ even), or the number $N$ (if $N$ odd).

Comment: @marco Oops, I forgot a case. I’ve fixed the answer again, sorry about that. My proof now matches your program.

Comment: @RossMillikan The last answer does match the $N=3$ case, in which the only coin flipped an odd number of times is $N=3$. so the only coin that is face down is $N=3$.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. The $N$ odd case it is easy to see as @auscrypt explained, the $N$ even case is the same with one more flip for the $N/2$-th and $N$-th coins, so their faces are reversed once more.

Comment: So it should be coin $N$ is down if $N$ is odd because it is flipped an odd number of times and $N/2$ alone is down if $N$ is even, but then $N$ is face up.